# Efficient reordering of coordinate pairs (2-tuples) in a list of pairs in Python

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I am wanting to zip up a list of entities with a new entity to generate a list of coordinates (2-tuples), but I want to assure that for (i, j) that i < j is always true.

However, I am not extremely pleased with my current solutions:

```
from itertools import repeat

mems = range(1, 10, 2) 
mem = 8

def ij(i, j):
  if i < j:
    return (i, j)
  else:
    return (j, i)

def zipij(m=mem, ms=mems, f=ij):
  return map(lambda i: f(i, m), ms)

def zipij2(m=mem, ms=mems):
  return map(lambda i: tuple(sorted([i, m])), ms)

def zipij3(m=mem, ms=mems):
  return [tuple(sorted([i, m])) for i in ms]

def zipij4(m=mem, ms=mems):
  mems = zip(ms, repeat(m))
  half1 = [(i, j) for i, j in mems if i < j]
  half2 = [(j, i) for i, j in mems[len(half1):]]

  return half1 + half2

def zipij5(m=mem, ms=mems):
  mems = zip(ms, repeat(m))
  return [(i, j) for i, j in mems if i < j] + [(j, i) for i, j in mems if i > j]
```

Output for above:

```
>>> print zipij() # or zipij{2-5}  
[(1, 8), (3, 8), (5, 8), (7, 8), (8, 9)]
```

Instead of normally:

```
>>> print zip(mems, repeat(mem))
[(1, 8), (3, 8), (5, 8), (7, 8), (9, 8)]
```

Timings: ***snipped (no longer relevant, see much faster results in answers below)***

For `len(mems) == 5`, there is no real issue with any solution, but for zipij5() for instance, the second list comprehension is needlessly going back over the first four values when `i > j` was already evaluated to be `True` for those in the first comprehension.

For my purposes, I'm positive that `len(mems)` will never exceed ~10000, if that helps form any answers for what solution is best. To explain my use case a bit (I find it interesting), I will be storing a sparse, upper-triangular, similarity matrix of sorts, and so I need the coordinate `(i, j)` to not be duplicated at `(j, i)`. I say *of sorts* because I will be utilizing the new `Counter()` object in 2.7 to perform quasi matrix-matrix and matrix-vector addition. I then simply feed `counter_obj.update()` a list of 2-tuples and it increments those coordinates how many times they occur.  SciPy sparse matrices ran about 50x slower, to my dismay, for my use cases... so I quickly ditched those.

So anyway, I was surprised by my results... The first methods I came up with were `zipij4` and `zipij5`, and yet they are still the fastest, despite building a normal `zip()` and then generating a new zip after changing the values. I'm still rather new to Python, relatively speaking (Alex Martelli, can you hear me?), so here are my naive conclusions:

- `tuple(sorted([i, j]))` is extremely expensive (Why is that?)
- `map(lambda ...)` seems to always do worse than a list comp (I think I've read this and it makes sense)
- Somehow `zipij5()` isn't much slower despite going over the list twice to check for i-j inequality. (Why is this?)

And lastly, I would like to know which is considered most efficient... or if there are any other fast and memory-inexpensive ways that I haven't yet thought of.  Thank you.

---

### Current Best Solutions

```
## Most BRIEF, Quickest with UNSORTED input list:
## truppo's
def zipij9(m=mem, ms=mems):
  return [(i, m) if i < m else (m, i) for i in ms]

## Quickest with pre-SORTED input list:
## Michal's
def zipij10(m=mem, ms=mems):
  i = binsearch(m, ms)  ## See Michal's answer for binsearch()
  return zip(ms[:i], repeat(m)) + zip(repeat(m), ms[i:])
```

### Timings

```
# Michal's  
Presorted - 410µs per loop
Unsorted - 2.09ms per loop  ## Due solely to the expensive sorted()

# truppo's
Presorted - 880µs per loop
Unsorted - 896µs per loop  ## No sorted() needed
```

Timings were using `mems = range(1, 10000, 2)`, which is only ~5000 in length. `sorted()` will probably become worse at higher values, and with lists that are more shuffled. `random.shuffle()` was used for the "Unsorted" timings.

Comment: @OP, since you specifically ask, I do hear you, but 4 hours after your post (which came at 3:30 AM my time!-), so of course by the time I'm reading this everything's been amply explored;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just inline your ij()-function?

```
def zipij(m=mem, ms=mems):
  return [(i, m) if i < m else (m, i) for i in ms]
```

(This runs in 0.64 ms instead of 2.12 ms on my computer)

**Some benchmarks:**

zipit.py:

```
from itertools import repeat

mems = range(1, 50000, 2)
mem = 8

def zipij7(m=mem, ms=mems):
  cpy = sorted(ms + [m])
  loc = cpy.index(m)

  return zip(ms[:(loc)], repeat(m)) + zip(repeat(m), ms[(loc):])

def zipinline(m=mem, ms=mems):
  return [(i, m) if i < m else (m, i) for i in ms]
```

Sorted:

```
>python -m timeit -s "import zipit" "zipit.zipinline()"
100 loops, best of 3: 4.44 msec per loop

>python -m timeit -s "import zipit" "zipit.zipij7()"
100 loops, best of 3: 4.8 msec per loop
```

Unsorted:

```
>python -m timeit -s "import zipit, random; random.shuffle(zipit.mems)" "zipit.zipinline()"
100 loops, best of 3: 4.65 msec per loop

p>python -m timeit -s "import zipit, random; random.shuffle(zipit.mems)" "zipit.zipij7()"
100 loops, best of 3: 17.1 msec per loop
```

Comment: OK, I didn't notice the slight difference in your answer, but it still is not running 10x faster than mine and Michal's as you claim...  Mine runs in ~0.5s, his runs in ~0.6s, and yours runs in about ~0.7s on mine.

Comment: Also, the list will have already been sorted anyway.. Mine is sorting inside the function and is still faster. I upped the list by 10x, mine runs in ~6s, Michal's in ~7s, and yours in ~8s.

Comment: I will still end up choosing your method, most likely, as I appreciate the brevity and simplicity... But it's still running slower on MY specific machine. I will test on other hardware sometime. :)

Comment: Are you using Python 3.0+ or something (where zip returns an iterator instead of a list)?
Have you tried the exact benchmark in this post?

Comment: Python 2.7a2 currently. Exact bench as yours: Yours = 3.9 msec per loop, mine = 2.94 msec per loop ... Shuffled: Yours = 4.01 msec per loop, mine = 11 msec per loop. But again I'm not arguing the problem with shuffling.  But I've already said that sorting of `mems` won't be factoring into my decision as it will be sorted already.

Comment: On Python 2.6.1 on my Mac mine is doing 2.92 msec per loop, and yours is doing 4.57. But indeed, even though the shuffling problem doesn't matter for my use, I can't pass up a one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

### Current version:

(Fastest at the time of posting with Python 2.6.4 on my machine.)

Update 3: Since we're going all out, let's do a binary search -- in a way which doesn't require injecting `m` into `mems`:

```
def binsearch(x, lst):
    low, high = -1, len(lst)
    while low < high:                                                           
        i = (high - low) // 2
        if i > 0:
            i += low
            if lst[i] < x:
                low = i
            else:
                high = i
        else:
            i = high
            high = low
    return i

def zipij(m=mem, ms=mems):
    i = binsearch(m, ms)
    return zip(ms[:i], repeat(m)) + zip(repeat(m), ms[i:])
```

This runs in **828 µs** = 0.828 ms on my machine vs the OP's current solution's 1.14 ms. Input list assumed sorted (and the test case is the usual one, of course).

This binary search implementation returns the index of the first element in the given list which is not smaller than the object being searched for. Thus there's no need to inject `m` into `mems` and sort the whole thing (like in the OP's current solution with `.index(m)`) or walk through the beginning of the list step by step (like I did previously) to find the offset at which it should be divided.

---

### Earlier attempts:

How about this? (Proposed solution next to `In [25]` below, 2.42 ms to zipij5's 3.13 ms.)

```
In [24]: timeit zipij5(m = mem, ms = mems)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.13 ms per loop

In [25]: timeit [(i, j) if i < j else (j, i) for (i, j) in zip(mems, repeat(mem))]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.42 ms per loop

In [27]: [(i, j) if i < j else (j, i) for (i, j) in zip(mems, repeat(mem))] == zipij5(m=mem, ms=mems)
Out[27]: True
```

Update: This appears to be just about exactly as fast as the OP's self-answer. Seems more straighforward, though.

Update 2: An implementation of the OP's proposed simplified solution:

```
def zipij(m=mem, ms=mems):
    split_at = 0
    for item in ms:
        if item < m:
            split_at += 1
        else:
            break
    return [(item, m) for item in mems[:split_at]] + [(m, item) for item in mems[split_at:]]

In [54]: timeit zipij()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.15 ms per loop
```

Also, truppo's solution runs in 1.36 ms on my machine. I guess the above is the fastest so far. Note **you need to sort `mems` before passing them into this function**! If you're generating it with `range`, it is of course already sorted, though.

Comment: Had no idea if/else could be used that way in list comprehensions... *sigh*  Thank you, though.  I'll be looking into this, but I still want to figure out my proposed method at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: This implementation runs slightly slower than my own, check the top of my answer, I've edited it in.  Comment on it if you'd like.  I'll see if I can tweak your implementation to best mine.

Comment: Well, I went foraging around my collection of implementations of basic algorithms and came up with this nice binary search. Using it seems to shave off almost 30% of the running time of your zipij7 for a pre-sorted list. Even when having to sort the input list (with a call like `zipij(ms=sorted(mems))`), the timing seems to be lower (although only very slightly). The gains would certainly be more pronounced with a longer input list.

Comment: I myself was wanting to replace my `index()` with a "binary search", but that was hard without knowing the name. I will be comparing this to truppo's, which (for me) is actually benching slower than my own answer, but not by very much. So my current solution is actually truppo's based on brevity.  I can make `binsearch()` a common utility function, though, so this new solution is still very brief. :)

Comment: Python allows one to control the behaviour of `<` and similar operators with instances of custom classes through the `__cmp__(self, other)` method. That makes functions such as this `binsearch` quite generic and therefore all the more useful as a library utilities. :-) It's also nice to have a version going the other way (that is, one which finds a lower, rather than an upper bound) -- or roll the two into one function accepting an optional argument to determine the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

### Most recent version:

```
def zipij7(m=mem, ms=mems):
  cpy = sorted(ms + [m])
  loc = cpy.index(m)

  return zip(ms[:(loc)], repeat(m)) + zip(repeat(m), ms[(loc):])
```

Benches slightly faster for me than truppo's, slower by 30% than Michal's. (Looking into that now)

---

I may have found my answer (for now). It seems I forgot about making a list comp version for `zipij()``:

```
def zipij1(m=mem, ms=mems, f=ij):
  return [f(i, m) for i in ms]
```

It still relies on my silly `ij()` helper function, so it doesn't win the award for brevity, certainly, but timings have improved:

```
# 10000
1.27s
# 50000
6.74s
```

So it is now my current "winner", and also does not need to generate more than one list, or use a lot of function calls, other than the `ij()` helper, so I believe it would also be the most efficient.

However, I think this could still be improved... I think that making N `ij()` function calls (where N is the length of the resultant list) is not needed:

- Find at what index `mem` would fit into `mems` when ordered
- Split mems at that index into two parts
- Do `zip(part1, repeat(mem))`
- Add `zip(repeat(mem), part2)` to it

It'd basically be an improvement on `zipij4()`, and this avoids N extra function calls, but I am not sure of the speed/memory benefits over the cost of brevity.  I will maybe add that version to this answer if I figure it out.

Comment: Exactly how do you measure? You latest solution is slower than the inlined version I suggested. Even with an already sorted list and low "m" it is still slower. With a large "m" and a shuffled list it is 10 times slower.

Comment: My latest solution? Definitely not..  Both Michal and I are getting twice as fast as the previous best solutions. Check his answer. I am timing differently than he is, but we are still getting the same results.  Our latest implementations differ slightly, though. Mine is slightly faster still.

Comment: I've updated my answer now with the exact benchmark I'm running